# Website loading only Preloader not content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help on http://aamlandscape.com/
I am stuck on this. when the website loads it only shows Preloader.
I inspect the error, it's because of JavaScript.
Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier.
plz help to solve this problem.

Comment: well, post the javascript that has the problem rather than expecting us to visit some rando website

Comment: Please go read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: And please don't post code in comments, that is hard to read. Edit your question to include necessary information, and go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I already check from my end , But i Did not understand How to solve this Problem.

Comment: there is no error in the code you posted in the comment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please remove A from function in main.js line number 286

Comment: Already Tried this. It's Not Working. I am using Cpanel editor .